# Visual Studio KB2829760 fatal error while uninstalling

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uninstallation

I need to reinstall vsial studio community, but when it was uninstalling, this is what it was saying:

**KB2829760 : Fatal error during installation.**

Any ideas what the hell is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hey! Atleast write in the comments why you freaking downvote!

Comment: facing the same issue. downvotes are just not know the answer that's why on the basis on the NULL knowledge they downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove or uninstall visual studio from CMD forcefully, use below command accordingly

```
D:\vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force
```

Refer to below answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28731368/1716709