# Can't uninstall Visual Studio 2015 (The storage control blocks were destroyed)

Tags: visual-studio, uninstallation

So I wanted to force an uninstallation of VS2015 Enterprise with "vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force", but I get an error message:

```
Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2999226) : The storage control blocks were destroyed.
```

I tried to restart my PC, so that Windows can apply that update, but it didn't work, the uninstall process always exits with that error.

I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I get this error and non of the solutions offered here or anywhere else work for me :(

Comment: @DavidAleu No I didn't, reinstalled it in a clean VM and it worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition I first when to the Control Panel > Programs and Features, tried to uninstall it that way.

Then found the following link:
[force uninstall a visual studio 2015 preview or release candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041688/force-uninstall-a-visual-studio-2015-preview-or-release-candidate)

Then navigated to `C:\ProgramData` and typed:

> dir /s vs_community.exe

It generated this useful path info:
`C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{50b32652-69d2-4b93-9316-edcd12067b8b}`

Then used Windows Explorer to go to that folder, `Shift + Right Click > Open command window here` and ran:

> vs_community.exe /uninstall /force

I then got this error screen after a LONG time...
[image: KB2999226 uninstall failure]

Then saw the below question:
[removing visual studio components left behind after an uninstall](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall.aspx)

So I tried to run:

> vs_community.exe /repair

It ended up hanging and I force quit it after about a half hour. Then I ran:

> vs_community.exe /uninstall /force

This time I checked the error log, and found the following line very near the bottom.
`Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, action: Uninstall, path: 2999226, arguments: '"C:\windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" /uninstall /kb:2999226 /quiet /norestart'`

Thought I had to install the `KB2999226` update because of the error:
`Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2999226) : The storage control blocks were destroyed.`

So I installed it, but `vs_community.exe` still wouldn't force uninstall.  I probably already had the update installed, but can't find out because my `windowsupdate.log` file only goes back a month or so?  Anyhow, my installing of the update probably didn't change anything.

According to the following articles:
[sysnative folder 64 bit windows](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm)
[File System Redirector - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx)

The `Windows7_MSU_x64` was trying to get to the `C:\Windows\System32` folder, but because I have a 64-bit version of Windows 7, it was trying to reach the `C:\windows\SysNative` folder, because it is an auto-redirect to the real `System32` folder.  For some reason I don't have a `SysNative` folder, so...

I then went to Windows Update and uninstalled the KB2999226 update and went back to:
`C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{50b32652-69d2-4b93-9316-edcd12067b8b}`

Ran the following again:

> vs_community.exe /uninstall /force

This time it worked and I got the screen:
[image: successful uninstall]

Comment: For me installing and then uninstalling the KB2999226 did make the forced uninstall complete successful, too. However, most of the files still existed as well as the entry in 'Programs and Features'... I ran /repair afterwards, which completed successfully and now I'm left with two entries in Programs and Features :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (WINDOWS 7) and I solved by making sure the following KB's were installed:

[KB3139923](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51558)

[KB3072630](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47955)

Having one installed without the presence of the other was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounters this again, the following did the trick for me:

1. Download and install KB2999226 from

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49093

2. Create a symbolic link from c:\Windowss\SysNative to c:\Windows\System32 using the following command line:

> mklink /D c:\Windows\SysNative c:\Windows\System32

3. Running the following command from command prompt:

> "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{68432bbb-c9a5-4a7b-bab3-ae5a49b28303}\vs_professional.exe" /uninstall /force

The {6844...} part might be different on different machines and the vs_professional.exe might be located at different location but I guess anyone should be able to search for it inside the "PackageCache" folder

Answer (score 0):

I had just the same issue. But for me nothing here has worked.

The only way worked for me was the standard way through the Windows Uninstall panel. The only difference here you have to reboot and uninstall it again until the option disappeared from the panel.

Answer (score 0):

The below steps fixed it for me.

First uninstall KB2999226:

```
wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:2999226 /quiet /norestart
```

Download and re-install KB2999226 (the one we just uninstalled above):

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49093
```

Uninstall Visual Studio from admin shell (you can use the install exe you originally used for the install):

```
vs_community.exe /uninstall /force
```