# Fail uninstall VS2015 on Win10 due to missing(?) KB2999226

Tags: uninstallation, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to uninstall VS2015 community edition on Windows 10 (64 bit) but it fails.

Referring to this SO post:[Can't uninstall Visual Studio 2015 (The storage control blocks were destroyed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379298/cant-uninstall-visual-studio-2015-the-storage-control-blocks-were-destroyed)

This question very well describes my problem, but I'm on Windows 10 where KB 2999226 apparently is not applicable. So why does VS2015 try to uninstall it and how can I convince it not to?

I've tried `vs_community.exe /uninstall /force` and I've tried [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller). Both fail with the same error. Here's an excerpt from the MSI log (`dd_vs_community_<timestamp>.log`):

```
[0884:29AC][2016-08-31T15:28:19]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: Windows7_MSU_x64
[1A74:2A60][2016-08-31T15:28:19]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, action: Uninstall, path: 2999226, arguments: '"C:\WINDOWS\SysNative\wusa.exe" /uninstall /kb:2999226 /quiet /norestart'
[1A74:2A60][2016-08-31T15:28:19]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0884:29AC][2016-08-31T15:28:19]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[0884:29AC][2016-08-31T15:28:19]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: Windows7_MSU_x64 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[0884:29AC][2016-08-31T15:28:19]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070057 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[0884:29AC][2016-08-31T15:28:19]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147024809 (0x80070057), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Uninstall, Package Id=Windows7_MSU_x64
[0884:29AC][2016-08-31T15:28:19]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[0884:29AC][2016-08-31T15:28:19]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, result: 0x80070057, restart: None
[0884:29AC][2016-08-31T15:28:19]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to execute MSU package.
```

It is possible that I installed VS2015 before I upgraded mu Windows 7 to Windows 10. In that case, possibly the VS 2015 installation required the KB when installed on my Windows 7, and installed it, which is recorded "somewhere". Then when I upgraded to Windows 10, the KB was removed. Now the VS uninstaller should ignore the KB entry in its uninstall process, but apparently fails to do so. If this is what happens, where can I modify the install log/info to remove the KB entry?

If additional info is needed to solve this, please just ask.

Comment: Uninstalling Visual Studio is often problematic. Usually the best thing to do is to never uninstall it and when you change/reformat your computer only install the versions you uses (and it is probably best to install older versions first if you want multiple versions).

Comment: I'm starting to realize that, but it doesn't really help im my current situation. I was going to install it again, just had some issues with some 3:rd party package I wanted to clean out... Maybe I can just leave it as is and install it fresh on top.

Comment: After repeated runs of Visual Studio Uninstaller and vs_community.exe /uninstall /force, I finally gave up. I manually removed VS 2015 (v14) folders under C:\Program Files (x86), ProgramData, AppData etc. and then did a fresh install from the web download on top of the "remains" of my prevous installation. It seems to have worked - the issues I had with the old installation seem to have been resolved and all settings etc. seem to have been reset to default.

Answer (score 0):

The KB2999226 is an update for CRT in Windows and is a component of the Windows operating system. It is included as a part of Windows 10, starting with the January Technical Preview, and it is available for older versions of the operating system via Windows Update.

1. Go to Control Panel—Programs and Features—View installed updates, if you can find the KB2999226, you can uninstall it, then uninstall the VS through the command: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{xxxxxx}\vs_community.exe" /uninstall /force, you can have a look at here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/ to find where the cached bundle is installed.
2. Download a healthy ISO file of VS community 2015 and use it to repair, after that, uninstall it using the above forcibly uninstall command in method 1.
3. Download and install the Windows Installer PowerShell Module tool to find all related components of VS 2015 and uninstall them, the detail information, check here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/14/how-to-install-visual-studio-to-another-directory-when-a-pre-release-is-installed/

Since the KB2999226 is shipped with Windows 10, your OS is Windows 10, it is not necessary to uninstall it unless you meet an issue that caused by it.

Comment: See comment in question above. I did do your step 1 before posting my question. It would have been interesting to try steps 2 and 3, but alas, your reply came after I had already went on with the fresh install which seems to have resolved my original problem. Thanks anyway and I'll be sure to try steps 2 and 3 if the need arises in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Missing KB2999226 , "Universal C Runtime" (curt) in windows 10.
Try to install "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017"
https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

I try [`VisualStudioUninstaller`](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases) and can succesfully uninstall,

see this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42105329/4573839