# Can not uninstall Visual Studio Express 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uninstallation

I want to install Visual Studio Community edition. I currently have Visual Studio 2015 Express installed, but I do not have enough space on my computer to keep both.

So, I wanted to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 Express. I opened Control Panel, found Visual Studio, clicked to uninstall it, nothing happened. Visual Studio got out of the list and it did not even uninstall. It still inside my computer.

I opened IOBit Uninstaller, found Visual Studio, did the same thing and nothing happened. It does not uninstall.

I thought downloading its setup file and uninstalling it from there would be great, so I did it. When I opened the setup file, an error came up saying that (approx.) "One or more specific components were not found.".

There is a Package Cache folder on my computer and I always remove it to get enough free space. It seems like that the uninstaller was there. I cleaned the registry using CCleaner and finally opened the setup file. It did not show any uninstallation option. I chose install and it installed Update 1. I wanted to uninstall it after installation, same thing happened, it did not uninstall. I opened the setup file and uninstalled it, it was still there after uninstallation was complete. Everything was mixed, I tried force uninstall and it did not work.

I used these methods:

- IOBit Uninstaller option
- CMD option
- The Visual Studio uninstaller on GitHub
- Its setup file
- Package Cache files
- Registry editing, registry cleaning.

None worked! How can I uninstall Visual Studio Express 2015?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but download Revo Uninstaller and that will get rid of it.

Comment: Does it matter? Or you can't install Community edition because it throw some error? Which error?

Comment: you should contact support. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/support-overview-vs.aspx

Comment: A project for my school was there, I want to get rid of messed up Express edition ASAP. Express edition on my computer does not work anymore and it takes a lot of space.

Comment: Can the off-topic voters please [read the help center for "what is on-topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), namely _"software tools commonly used by programmers"_? Thanks.

Comment: @CodeCaster, this is an edge case. It *is* about a tool primarily used for programming, but installation issues do not fall squarely in on-topic territory on SO I believe.

Comment: @maxshuty, question [fits](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) SO: *"software tools commonly used by programmers"*. I personally don't think it's a real problem. Any software may leave something after itself (some `AppData` folders, registry enters, dlls, etc). Clean re-install of Windows were and still recommended thing to do in such cases.

Comment: @Fred sure, but there's plenty of questions on tool (un)installations that are allowed. :) I think it fits nicely here. Anyway, OP: read the installation log.

Comment: @CodeCaster not off topic really? then answer this question.

Comment: @M.kazem that's a [non sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic)). I can perfectly determine what is on-topic or not without being able to provide the answer.

Comment: btw if the uninstaller is gone and you cant get the rid of all trash just install VS again and then perform clean uninstall

Comment: I reiterate, just download revo uninstaller. I had the same exact issue on my brothers laptop. I tried a force uninstall, nothing would work. Found someone saying to try Revo, downloaded that and it uninstalled it fine.

Comment: I also used Revo, installed again and tried to uninstall it. It was still there, this is kinda rare and also a weird issue.

Comment: @SultanlıƏlif Did you use Revo and uninstall all the associated files with it? Have you tried `installer_name.exe /u /force` in cmd?

Comment: Yes, I also tried that. It did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041688/force-uninstall-a-visual-studio-2015-preview-or-release-candidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control Panel is enough. Have you tried a simple reboot?
Sometimes if you close the program, some process run anyway.

- Reboot Windows
- Don't start nothing
- Try to uninstall

Comment: @SultanlıƏlif Safe Mode uninstall?

Comment: I did not try that one. I will try this ^

Comment: This method worked. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @SultanlıƏlif Hey that was another person.. me... Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ.. My answer below :0

Comment: Thanks both of you, lol :D

Comment: @SultanlıƏlif But then you should have accepted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling in Safe Mode.

For more info on booting in safe mode:

- [Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/5-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-8-windows-81)
- [Windows 10](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)