# Could not find a suitable SDK to target

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, win-universal-app, uwp

I try to create a project for UWP but I get this error:

[image]

Comment: add more info please.

Comment: i reinstall VS comunity 2015 update 2, i open old project then get error: One or more projects require a platform SDK (UAP, Version: 10.0.10586.0) that is either not installed or is included as pat of a future update to Visual Studio. Install the platform SDK to open these projects.

Comment: So, ti try create new project but it can't create project and get error: Could not find a suitable SDK to target. I install both SDK 10 and 8.1. Thanks!

Comment: Just used VS2015 to install the SDK support, it whirled away for an hour or two and then gives me this exact same error. I'll leave this crap alone for another year, I guess!

Comment: FWIW, I went to Control Panel, Visual Studio 2015, clicked Change.  Instead of installing the very top Windows 10 SDK in the install, I installed the next prior version.   That worked!

Answer (score 8):

I install windows development kit and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What do you mean by you installed "windows development kit"? Where did you get it? Can I download it somewhere?

Comment: i get it here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: It was already installed on my pc. Downloaded it and said it was fully up to date. So still same issue... and as @Kampmarsvin suggested, sorry but I do not like an older sdk (below 14933 anniversary update)

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem can be solved by choosing an older sdk. Choose the second newest from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Comment: I had the latest 2 SDKs installed.  Uninstalling the newest SDK (leaving just the second newest SDK) fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the latest SDK didn't help me either. The installer wouldn't complete, kept getting to 97% and then rolling back.

I had a whole load of MDMERGE errors like:

MDMERGE : error MDM2009: Duplicate type Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.TetheringOperationalState found processing metadata file C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\Temp\UnionWinmdWorkingFolder\26178\WinMDs\Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorsTetheringContract.winmd, type already exists in file C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\Temp\UnionWinmdWorkingFolder\26178\WinMDs\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd.

To resolve this I deleted References in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10

..and reinstalled. Seems like older kit installs are interfering with new kit installs.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install Windows SDK 10.0.10586. 
(control panel -> visual studio -> modify -> sdk)

Installing newer versions of the SDK would just give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly this error occurred for me when trying to create a new solution using a class library for the initial project. The library had the same name as the project. After deleting the two empty directories it managed to leave behind I changed the project type to a console app and it created the solution and console project just fine. I was then able to add the class library project with no issues.

It's always something!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and have had the same error. Answers in this post gave me the idea to create console application.

I created a C++ Console application. While doing that, I was prompted with a dialog that allowed me to switch from console application to DLL. In addition, I chose a blank project. Once I performed those steps, the blank DLL project was created, and I did not get the *Could not find a suitable SDK to target* error.